# IBM AIX std::clock()?

Tags: c++, aix

I execute in IBM AIX the following code.

```
int main(void)
{
    printf( "start\n");
    double time1 = (double)clock();      /* get initial time */
    time1 = time1 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;      /*    in seconds    */

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(5));

    /* call clock a second time */
    double time2 = (((double)clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    double timedif = time2 - time1;
    printf( "The elapsed time is %lf seconds, time1:%lf time2:%lf CLOCKS_PER_SEC:%ld\n", 
            timedif));
}
```

The result is:

> 2018-04-07 09:58:37 start
>   
>  2018-04-07 09:58:42 The elapsed time is 0.000180 seconds, time1:0.000000
>   time2:0.000181 CLOCKS_PER_SEC:1000000

I don't know why elapsed time is 0.000180 (why not 5)?

Comment: Despite its name, the `clock` function does not measure the so called "wall clock time", but (as the man pages say) the CPU time, which only your process accounts for if it is actually doing something which is CPU-bound. Not very likely to be ever as long as the same amount of execution, wallclock, time (think I/O, sleeps, other waiting that does not account for CPU time of course). Use `gettimeofday`, for example to measure elapsed wall clock time.

Comment: @OP: Please edit your post, fix the syntactical and other errors. Also, if you can, use sleep/usleep/nanosleep

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual

> Returns the processor time consumed by the program.

It is CPU time consumed by a program, it is not a physical time. A sleeping program does not consume CPU time. Thus in raw words, it is time interval from `main` till `sleep` plus time interval after `sleep` till return.

If you want to get system/real time, look at the `std::chrono::system_clock` class.

```
#include <chrono>
using std::chrono::system_clock;
system_clock::time_point time_now = system_clock::now();
```

Comment: I used boost::timer but do i have to use boost::timer::cpu_timer, right?

Comment: Yes, you may use `boost::timer::cpu_timer` for measurements. You may look at `boost::chrono` namespace too.

Comment: btw no `<chrono>` on AIX or I'm missing something?